# Bootstrap3 random columns per row

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've been working on a new website ([feed-monster.com](https://feed-monster.com/) fyi) for the past few weeks and have been displaying articles 2 per row on md/lg/s screens and 1 per row on xs screens.

I recently went in and adjusted it to look a little better, First row = 3 columns, 2nd = 1, 3rd (and beyond) = 2.

But now I want to make it keep going with that cycle or randomly set the number of columns per row, 1-3 cols.

I iterate over the rows (listi variable) and then calculate what the column should have.

```
    if(listi == 1){
        _col='col-md-4 col-sm-4';
    }else if(listi == 2){
        _col='col-md-4 col-sm-4';
    }else if(listi == 3){
        _col='col-md-4 col-sm-4';
    }else if(listi == 4){
        _col='col-md-12 col-sm-12';
    } else _col='col-md-6 col-sm-6';

    _item=$( "<div>", {
         "class": _col+ " col-xs-12"
    });
```

I would love to read some ideas on how to do this better.

**option 1**) repeat this processes for all rows so you always get a 3,1,2 setup for all of the records.

**option 2**) randomly set how many columns (1-3) per row, ideally preventing the same # of cols repeating twice, ie no 3,2,2,1.

I can figure this out but thought it'd be a good post for stack since I didn't really find much searching around.

I am using jQuery so answers can certainly include that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why not using Masonry, it's more beautiful and fit with the size of the content of each column

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying not to use any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing the random method trying to prevent duplicate column sets per row, it does that up till the end as it over-rides the random col to ensure we dont do more cols then avail (probably some way to tweek that).

```
var perrow=rand(1,3);
var justadded=0;
var used=totalrows;

function builditem(){
    use=(totalrows-used);

    if(justadded == perrow){
        oldperrow=perrow;

        do {
            perrow=rand(1,3);
        }
        while (perrow == oldperrow);

        if(perrow > use) perrow=use;
        justadded=0;
    }

    justadded++;
    used++;

    if(perrow == "1"){
        _col='col-md-12 col-sm-12';
    }else if(perrow =="2"){
        _col='col-md-6 col-sm-6';
    }else if(perrow =="3") _col='col-md-4 col-sm-4';
}

function addmoreitems(data){
                    totalrows=Object.keys(data).length;
                    used=0;
                    use=0;
                    justadded=0;
                    ran=3;
                    if(totalrows < ran) ran = totalrows;
                    perrow=rand(1,ran);
}
```